# vscode pytorch tensorboard install error is appeared

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

I want to import tensorboard. but in vscode, i saw Launch TensorBoard Session.
after i click that, this error appeard

Could not install tensorboard. If pip is not available, please use the package manager of your choise to manually install this library into your python environment

tensorboard version 2.1.0
python 3.7.3
torch 2.0.1+cu117
pip version  20.3.4

1. pip upgrade
2. pip install torch_tb_profiler(this command make error)

> > status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: don't click it, it is just a hint, you should install tensorboard by using pip or pip.exe firstly. then you can click it.